# Drush Drupal temp folder

Tags: mysql, windows, drupal-7, drush

I have two Drupal 7 sites. I want to keep them in sync with a drush command:

```
drush sql-sync SOURCE DEST
```

when I answer `y` to overwrite the databases I get the following error:

```
mysqldump: Can't create/write to file '/tmp/filename.sql' (errorcode 2 - no such file or directory)
```

both of my sites are running on a windows 2012 R2 server. So the temp folder should be d:\temp. If I go to a command prompts and type `echo %TEMP%` it returns d:\temp.

Anyone have any suggestions? According to everything I can find, this should work fine on windows.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [example.drushrc.php](http://api.drush.org/api/drush/examples%21example.drushrc.php/5.x) file there is a `$options['dump-dir']` option which you should set if the temporary directory is not `/tmp`